# Can PDFbox be used in html,php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdfbox

I made a desktop application by using PDFbox in Netbeans.Now I wish to develop a web application of same.Can PDFbox be used to make web app using html,php and javascript?
I haven't started working on backend yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you use the command line utilities, or develop your own, and then call them from your php / javascript code. See here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html

and here people who call PDFBox from php:

https://github.com/chelmertz/PDFBox-php

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9028-PHP-Extract-text-from-PDF-documents-using-PDFBox-tool.html